# Error with flask API JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, api, flask

Below is the code I'm executing for post request and getting this error

> JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0) error

```
import requests,json
request_data = {"files": ["\\r\\tabs\\lg\\supp\\p\\tabrvstring\\TStringManager.h @ 118",
               "\\qt\\VION\\localbase\\base\\kernel\\qobject.cpp @ 1418"]}

response = requests.post('http://autobot/_search/api/v1.0/',
                         headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'},data = json.dumps(request_data))

print("Status code: ", response.status_code)
print("Printing Entire Post Request")
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? Accept it

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't have domain: `http://autobot###/_search/api/v1.0/`.

If write `.com` and `response.json()` the same error raised. Because `response` doesn't have `json` data. Try to breakpoint or `print(response.text)`.

For convert from text to json use `json.loads(response.text)`.

```
import requests, json
request_data = {"files": ["\\r\\tabs\\lg\\supp\\p\\tabrvstring\\TStringManager.h @ 118",
               "\\qt\\VION\\localbase\\base\\kernel\\qobject.cpp @ 1418"]}

url = 'http://autobot.com/_search/api/v1.0/'
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
data = json.dumps(request_data)
response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = data)

print("Status code: ", response.status_code)
print("Printing Entire Post Request")
#print(response.json())
print(response.text)

# Status code:  200
# Printing Entire Post Request
# <html><head><title>autobot.com</title></head><body><h1>autobot.com</h1><p>Coming soon.</p></body></html>
```

Comment: In my case data receiving as json format .But cross domain show errors